# How to change border color of checkbox in flutter / dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a checkbox added to my UI in Flutter app, I can see checkbox color or active color property but can't find any option to change border color of checkbox , which is usually black.

Whats the provision or tweak to change the border color ?

Comment: AFAIK,`Container` has border property.

Comment: Tried it but I was required to adjust the container as per the size of checkbox I didn't find it elegant

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
Checkbox(value: false, tristate: false, onChanged: () {});
　　↓
Theme(
data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.red),
child: Checkbox(value: false, tristate: false, onChanged: (bool value) {}));

No onChanged, then the border will be grey(disabled).
```

Comment: Glad, I was able to help!

Comment: It should be mentioned, that the Checkbox requires the `onChanged` parameter, otherwise the inactive colors are used and ThemeData does not bring any changes

Answer (score 27):

You can do it by using `side` property...

```
side: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff585858)),
```

Comment: Simplest answer, thanks! The side property has preference over ThemeData and CheckboxThemeData.

Answer (score 8):

is case you wanna define app-wide theme for your checkboxes you can do this:

```
MaterialApp(
   ...
  theme:ThemeData(
    checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
      fillColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
        (states) {
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
           return Colors.purple // the color when checkbox is selected;
            }
         return Colors.white //the color when checkbox is unselected;
         },
    ),
   ),
  ),
 )
```

it is a good practice to define app-wide theme for your app to avoid code duplication and ensure consistency it also provides better maintenance.
enjoy coding:)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
        Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                top: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.red),
                left: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.red),
                right: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.red),
                bottom: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
            child: Checkbox(value: false, onChanged: null),
            width: 20,
            height: 20),
```

The `BoxDecoration` class contains `border` property that will let you customize the border sides and then you can add a `Checkbox` and match the width and height of the container to the checkbox

Comment: ThemeData is a much more effective way of setting the border.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can change the color of text box outline

```
Checkbox(value: isChecked, onChanged: (val){
                      if(val != null) {
                        isChecked = val;
                        setState(() {
                        });
                      }
                    },checkColor: theme.primaryColor,
                    activeColor: theme.whiteColor,
                    hoverColor: theme.whiteColor,
                    side: BorderSide(
                      color: whiteColor, //your desire colour here
                      width: 1.5,
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `side` its simple.

Ex - `side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Transform.scale( //For Increasing or decreasing Sizes 
                  scale: 1.3,
                  child: Theme( // For Color Change, 
                    data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: AppColors.checkBoxBorderColor),
                    child: Checkbox(
                      value: true,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( // Making around shape
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2)),
                      onChanged: (isCheck) {},
                      activeColor: AppColors.checkBoxActiveColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the border color using below code.

```
   Checkbox(
      value: _isChecked,
      onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() => _isChecked = value),
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
    )
```